# Flex 3 - Rounded bottom corners on a window?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, air

I'm making a flex 3.5a/air2 application and I've made a popup window but I can't seem to get its bottom corners rounded. Setting cornerRadius seems to only affect the top corners.

There doesn't seem to be a roundedBottomCorners property like there is for panels, and adding a controlbar with a cornerRadius also has no effect.

I'm sure this is a very simple problem but would really appreciate any help as I can't find the answer on google or after searching on here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can give up window header (and paint it yourself), try to make transparent window (with transparent background) and construct it from controls you need. I'm sure you can get window of any shape this way.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up making the window transparent and setting showFlexChrome to false. Then using a container I was able to get rounded corners.

It didn't help my other problem which was trying to get a glow effect around the window and still being able to resize it.. for that I had to override the mouseDownHandler from the window class so I could modify the drag locations to the container canvas. What a pain!